# Python: split array into variables

Tags: python, list

I have a function that returns a list. The length of this list is unknown to the caller.

```
def get_array():
    ret = [1, 2]
    return ret

var1, var2 = get_array()
```

This sets `var1 = 1` and `var2 = 2`. This works fine with all lists except when the length is less than 2. For example, if the list has length of 1:

```
 def get_array():
    ret = [1]
    return ret

 var1 = get_array()
```

This sets `var1` to `[1]`, but I want `var1` to be `1`. Is there a cleaner way to unpack this array without having to check its length?

Comment: What? You obviously need to know its length to decide how many variables to use on the left-hand side of the assignment. In any case, what's the point?

Comment: `var1, = get_array()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using python3, you can use the splatted unpacking syntax to help you out here:

```
In [113]: a,*b = [1]

In [114]: a
Out[114]: 1

In [115]: b
Out[115]: []
```

Basically, this lets you unpack `get_array()[1:]` into `b`, which will be empty, if `get_array()` returns a list of size 1

Answer (score 3):

Sure, if the size of the resulting list is known, use the same notation:

```
var1, = [1]  # var1 is set to 1
```